# What is the alternative of html form in php?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am sending email when user post some data using some form. This is the condition for sending email

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

$message='Thanks for registerring yourself';
    require "public/api/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  

    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 587;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = '*********'; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = '*********'; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $email = $_POST['InputEmail'];
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress($email, "RahulName"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
    unset($mail);

}
?>
```

Form declaration is like this .When i m using this,I  am able to send email but the form data is not going in database.

```
  <form method="post" id="login_form" action="" >
```

But when I m using this i m able to send data in database but not email.

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
```

What is the solution to do both the things ?

Comment: this is not the problem of mysql.

Comment: what is alternative of <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>  in html ?

Comment: I have uploaded the mail code also.

Comment: The only alternative for this function in HTML is the `<form>` tag. But it is not an alternative, because `form_open_multipart` generates this tag. So, they are the same. To solve your problem you have to save data to DB manually in your `if` block before or after an email is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using **CodeIgniter**.

For your question the equivalent HTML code is

`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="login_form" action="">`

You should refer CI's User Guide [CI Form Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

As well look at the source code of the helper file: [Source Code - FormHelper](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/source-function-form_open_multipart.html#97-109)

Hope this helps.

Comment: As @Dwand says, you should write the PHP code to get the Form Data and save into database. I assume you have done that. But I am not seeing any code snippet of DB interaction in your code. If still you are not able to solve, either enhance your question or publish entire code, so that we can help